# Flutter error: the instance 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

I'm getting this error while implementing agora ui kit.
**Error**

> The instance member widget can't be accessed in an initializer.

```
import 'package:agora_uikit/agora_uikit.dart';

class LiveStream extends StatefulWidget {
  const LiveStream({
    Key key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.channelname,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final String channelname;
  @override
  _LiveStreamState createState() => _LiveStreamState();
}

class _LiveStreamState extends State<LiveStream> {
  final AgoraClient client = AgoraClient(
    agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
      appId: "--AppID--",
      channelName: widget.channelname,
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple trick is using `late` keyword,

```dart
class _LiveStreamState extends State<LiveStream> {
  late final AgoraClient client = AgoraClient(
    agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
      appId: "--AppID--",
      channelName: widget.channelname,
    ),
  );
```

Or you can use `initState`

```dart
class LiveStream extends StatefulWidget {
  const LiveStream({
    Key? key,
    required this.width,
    required this.height,
    required this.channelname,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double width;
  final double height;
  final String channelname;
  @override
  _LiveStreamState createState() => _LiveStreamState();
}

class _LiveStreamState extends State<LiveStream> {
  late final AgoraClient client;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    client = AgoraClient(
      agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
        appId: "--AppID--",
        channelName: widget.channelname,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: After first option it shows: Unexpected text 'late'. Try removing the text.
And the second: 1. Unexpected text 'late'. Try removing the text.
2. The final variable 'client' must be initialized. Try initializing the variable

Comment: aren't you using null-safety?

Comment: No. Is it required for it?

Comment: It would be great if you start using null safety, coz everything on flutter is using null-safety. More about [migration](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)  Or just remove `late final` and use second option using constructor.

Comment: please tell how can I do it with the constructor

Comment: oh sorry, I mean using `initState`, the second option

Comment: But it would be best if you start using null-safety

Comment: As I said in first comment the second option gave errors. Should I remove late final from the second option?

Comment: Yes remove those and use `AgoraClient client;`

Comment: It is not compiling even now.

Comment: Consider upgrading your project to null safety and flutter v3, you can get support easily and can avoid unwanted issue.

Comment: Before when I was using static channel name then the video streaming was working.
but now when I used the dynamic allocation of channel name then the he streaming isn't working. Is it because of the way we are calling the function in init?

Comment: Cant say for sure from this snippet, but I think not. Because initState ensure of initialization until it is future.